# How to add caption to images in <p> when in <p> only inline elements are allowed?

Tags: html, image, formatting, semantics, semantic-markup

This is new for me: only inline elements are allowed in `<p> </p>`, in HTML. Then how can I make captions for images in my HTML paragraphs? I have this, but it uses a div, which is not allowed in `<p>`:

```
<div class='image floatright' style='width:228px;margin:0 0 0 10px;'>
  <a rel='article' href='images/articles/comenius_logo.jpg' title=''>
    <img style='width:218px' src='images/articles/comenius_logo.jpg' alt='' />
  </a>
  Caption of the image
</div>
```

I could place this outside the paragraph, but then it would be at the top, which I don't always want.
And I also could use divs instead of paragraphs, but then the semantics of the html source code would be lost.

I don't know what I can do :\ All of the solutions I have found use block elements, like table, div, figure, etc.

Comment: You can replace the `<div>` with a `<span>`, and set `display:block;`, to achieve the same effect without a block-element.

Comment: Thank You, it's a great idea. Why didn't you write it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `<div>` with a `<span>`, then style it using `display:block;`. The `<span>` is still an inline element (even if it looks like a block-level element), thus passes the HTML validation.